# React Props doesn't update the state

Tags: reactjs, state

What is wrong with the below code in react? I see that the props are shown up with a delay (based on console.log) but other than that I don't see what is the issue here.

```
  state = {
    data: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      email: "",
    },
    errors: {},
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    const { firstName, lastName, email } = this.props.user;
    var changeData = { ...this.state.data };
    changeData.firstName = firstName || "";
    changeData.lastName = lastName || "";
    changeData.email = email || "";
    if (firstName) {
      console.log(changeData);
      this.setState({ data: { changeData } });
    }
  }
```

I don't see the data being changed in the state....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`changeData` is already an object no need to wrap with `{}` change your code like below

`this.setState({ data: changeData });`

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right, though  there is another issues which I am not seing. it doesn't read in the `this.props.user` for some reason. I have passed this to this form though `    <AboutMe user={this.state.user} />` in a parent component, where `this.state.user` is written to the console as real data, though I don't think it is being passed to child, looks to me that after some time only.

Comment: I will suggest create another issue for that or add more details to your question otherwise it's hard to suggest you proper answer. And if my answer was helpful to you , accept the answer and give a upvote, thanks.